# Bibtex file does not compile

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've been googling for hours and found many related issues but still don't understand what's gone wrong. i have run latex and bib at least 1000 times. 
In the dropdown menu I use "pdflatex" for my latex file and "bibtex" for my bib file. I am using Texworks. Also, I should say this has worked previously on another computer.

here's my bib file:

```
@article{paper,
author={name},
title="{title}",
journal={J. Phys. Conf. Ser.},
volume={67},
number={},
 pages={23},
 year={2007}
}
```

and this is my latex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\begin{document}
\title{Autumn Term Report}
\author{myself}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

  HI
\cite{paper}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{trial.bib}
\end{document}
```

and here's my bbl file (empty! so i think bibtex musn't be compiling)

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Also, in my output pdf i get a "References" section but the article is not listed there, and there's a question mark where i refer to it in the main body.

Comment: It sounds like you're compiling the `.bib` file ... ? You should not be doing that. You should be running `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, and then `latex` again. `bibtex` should be run on the `.aux` file, but it's best if you just don't specify a file extension, depending on how you're calling `bibtex`. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: It is not `\cite{@paper}` but `\cite{paper}`. Remove `@`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) Sorry on two accounts
First, the \cite{@paper} problem is a typo i made when creating this minimal example. Having fixed this now, i still have the same problem.
secondly, maybe i'm using incorrect terminology. By "compiling" i mean pressing on the green button with a triangle inside it. I guess that is "running". Anyways, as I said above I have done this about a thousand times without success, including what you've suggested. Both things have been edited in my original post

Comment: sorry - my minimal example is now working. however my actual document is still not working. i really don't understand what's going on!

Comment: @user50563 - If your real file still won't compile properly (after removing the extension `.bib` from the argument of `\bibliography`), I suggest you post a new query in which you condense your "real" file to the minimum amount that still generates the problem (or problems).

Answer (score 8):

You have to use `\cite{paper}` without `@`. Also, don't use the extension in `\bibliography{trial}`. Having said this, you have to run this compile sequence assuming that your main file is named `myfile.tex`

```
pdflatex myfile
bibtex myfile
pdflatex myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

Code (`myfile.tex`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{trial.bib}
  @article{paper,
author={name},
title="{title}",
journal={J. Phys. Conf. Ser.},
volume={67},
number={},
 pages={23},
 year={2007}
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\title{Autumn Term Report}
\author{myself}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

  HI
\cite{paper}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{trial}    %% no .bib needed
\end{document}
```

[image]